# PostGIS: Extract polygon of area within # vertical meters of summit altitude from a tiled raster DEM

Tags: postgis

I have a PostGIS tiled-raser table with 30x30m DEM data for NZ at national level.

I have a table of summit point locations and altitudes.

I want to work out the polygon that encloses the area within # vertical meters of each summit.

I have the following working solution but it is *very* slow (2 queries per minute on my PC).  Any suggestions as to a better way?

```
SELECT val, ST_AsText(geom) AS geom FROM 
(SELECT (ST_DumpAsPolygons(
  ST_Reclass(
    ST_Union(
      ST_Clip(
        rast,  
        ST_Buffer(
          ST_GeomFromText(
            'POINT(#{summit.location.x} #{summit.location.y})',
            4326
          ),
        #{dist_max})
      )
    ),
    1,
    '0-#{alt_min}:0,#{alt_min}-#{alt_max}:1',
    '8BUI')
  )
).* from dem30s) 
AS foo WHERE val=1 and ST_Contains(
  geom, 
  ST_GeomFromText('POINT(#{summit.location.x} #{summit.location.y})',4326)
);
```

Explanation of the above:

- ST_Clip is to limit the queried area to a reasonable distance for processing efficiency (I've been limiting to 0.02 degrees (~2km))
- ST_Union is because I have a tiled raster and need to run the query on an single contiguous raster
- ST_Reclass - set the area I'm after to '1' so it falls in a single polygon
- ST DumpAsPolygons - extract area reclassed as '1' as polygons
- WHERE ST_Contains - only return the polygon that contains the original centroid, not any outlying polygons.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this query :

```
WITH
    -- A temp table to get the Z of each points from the DEM
    ext_points AS (
        SELECT 
            points.*,   -- The all columns from points table
            -- The Z from the nearest pixel
            ST_NearestValue(rast, geom) as Z
        FROM points
        -- NB: I use a CROSS JOIN because my raster is not tiled
        CROSS JOIN dem
    ),
    -- A new temp table with a polygonal extraction of pixels (can be slow)
    poly_raster AS (
        SELECT (ST_DumpAsPolygons(rast, 1)).* 
        FROM dem
    -- A table who contains the filtred pixels
    ), t AS (
        SELECT ext_points.id, poly_raster.*
        FROM ext_points
        JOIN poly_raster
            -- We take only the pixel at 5 meters from the summits
            -- NB: The value is in CRS Units
            ON st_dwithin(poly_raster.geom, ext_points.geom, 5)
            -- We filter with the Z value
            AND val between (Z - 10) AND (Z + 10)       
    )
-- The pixels are grouped
SELECT id, 
    st_union(geom) as geom, 
    min(val) as z_min, 
    max(val) as z_max,
    count(*) as p_number 
FROM t
GROUP BY id;
```